# Could we make Mandatory Field null in test class?

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage, failing-tests

I have custom object ABC__c .
i have mandatory custom field Account__c on this object which is a master detail.

Can we make this fields as null in a test class?

Comment: Depends what you need to do with it. If the data never touches the database, then it does not matter which fields are populated. Even if you need to hit the database, some MD configurations allow child records to be "orphaned", so you might be able to delete the parent after inserting the child.

Comment: are you trying to do code coverage of an `if (myObj.Account__c == null) {...}`?  If field is mandatory, such line of code is superfluous

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot make any field that is required at the database level `null` in a test class, or in any other context.

A need to do this is usually an indicator of a design flaw, either in the test, or in the schema, or in the business logic. Possibly this shouldn't be a master-detail field at all.

Comment: thanks for the answer but the field is master detail with standard object account